# maven-surefire-plugin не видит некоторые Kotlin-тесты на JUnit5

Tags: kotlin, maven, junit

При сборке Maven-проекта с кодом, написанным на Kotlin'е, с тестами, написанными с использованием JUnit5, почему-то maven-surefire-plugin не видит некоторые функции/методы:

- @Test-функции, которые не начинаются с префикса **test** (Причем сам **test** не подходит);
- @TestFactory-функции.

При этом, IntelliJ IDEA все тесты прекрасно считывает.

Версии, с которыми экспериментировал:

- Maven: 3.6.0, 3.6.1

  - maven-surefire-plugin: 2.22.2
- JDK: JDK 1.8.0_201, OpenJDK 11.0.2, AdoptOpen 11.0.2
- Kotlin: 1.3.72
- JUnit: 5.6.3, 5.7.1

**Пример**:

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>

        <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.3</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

src/test/kotlin/MyTest.kt:

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest.dynamicTest
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestFactory

class MyTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        println("test")
    }

    @Test
    fun test1() {
        println("test1")
    }

    @TestFactory
    fun tests() = listOf<DynamicTest>(
        dynamicTest("Тест2") { println("test2") }
    )

    @Test
    fun test3() {
        println("test3")
    }
}
```

Вывод Maven'а:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running MyTest
test3
test1
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 s - in MyTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

При этом в сети много статей о том, как отлично работает Maven+Kotlin+JUnit5:

- https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/junit-5-kotlin
- https://habr.com/ru/post/346452

А проблему, как у меня, нигде в сети я так и не нашел.

Прошу помочь с решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удивительно!

После дня безуспешных поисков решений и уже написания вопроса здесь от безысходности. Обнаружил ответ на свой вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229689/junit-maven-tests-are-being-found-but-not-executed):

Необходимо было всего лишь добавить в зависимости артефакт:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Опубликуйте ответ на вопрос не как ссылку, а нормальным русским языком. Иначе - ссылка не является ответом.

Comment: @zed, поправил.